# Insert IP address into table from form

Tags: php, sql, forms

When my PHP form is submitted I am trying to get the end users IP address and insert it into the database table with the record.

My form posts to another php page.:

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="http://x.com/promotions/boston_mailer.php">
<table border="0"> ...etc...
```

I set my boston_mailer.php to grab the IP address:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
            ucm_signup 
            ( fname, lname, email, phone, iama, buyfrom, ipaddress )
        VALUES
            ( '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[mail]', '$_POST[phone]',
              '$_POST[iama]', '$_POST[buyfrom]', '$_SERVER[$ipaddress]')";
```

My DB table (phpMyAdmin) has a column named "ipaddress" and is set as VARCHAR with 30 size.

When I submit the form the IP address is nil. "". What am I missing? Do I need to put something in my form.php page? Thank you

Comment: You may also want to consider storing your ip address as a decimal value (http://www.geektools.com/geektools-cgi/ipconv.cgi)

Comment: I'm guessing this is churning out a lot of `Use of undefined constant fname` type notices? It also looks vulnerable to SQL injection - interpolating variables into queries isn't the best idea, much worse when they're not sanitised. As an aside - `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` isn't entirely reliable for uniquely identifying a visitor (routers, proxies, load balancing systems ...)

Comment: @CD001 I actually did not know where to find the errors. I will look into interpolating variables into queries, do you have a reference suggestion on what else to do?

Comment: Your absolute best bet, for executing SQL with PHP, is to use PDO and either bound parameters or bound values (if you're not updating the parameters with the response from a stored procedure) : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php - never trust input data from userland :| mysqli also supports bound parameters : http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: @CD001 Is using bound values OR bound parameters secure from SQL injection or do you need both?

Comment: Bound Values and Bound Parameters are both safe from SQL injection - you choose which to use when you create your Statement; it's not the same as just building an SQL string and throwing it at the database server, you build a Statement object, bind parameters (or values) to it and then execute it : the full PDO manual is here http://uk1.php.net/pdo . The main difference between bound parameters and values is that parameters are variables passed by reference so they can be updated by the response from the SQL server ... values are just values, they go in and they don't come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$_SERVER[$ipaddress]` on your query just send `$ipaddress` , because `$_SERVER[$ipaddress]` is undefined.

The right way...

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];   
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
            ucm_signup 
            ( fname, lname, email, phone, iama, buyfrom, ipaddress )
        VALUES
            ( '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[mail]', '$_POST[phone]',
              '$_POST[iama]', '$_POST[buyfrom]', '$ipaddress')";
```

Comment: That makes sense, +1 for the explanation. :)